# aggregate functions in microsoft access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table as follows:

```
userid  checktime                checktype
------------------------------------------
213     10/30/2014 2:06:09 PM    O
592     10/30/2014 2:28:04 PM    I
714     10/30/2014 10:02:59 AM   O
714     10/30/2014 10:03:01 AM   O
147     10/30/2014 1:05:15 PM    O
147     10/30/2014 1:05:20 PM    I
147     10/30/2014 1:13:17 PM    O
147     10/30/2014 1:13:23 PM    I
213     10/30/2014 11:56:11 AM   I
147     10/30/2014 1:08:26 PM    O
147     10/30/2014 1:08:32 PM    I
```

How can I select users who have record with checktype of 'I' only or with checktype of 'O' only, not with both? Please I want the query to be compatible with Microsoft Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that a boolean TRUE is represented as -1 and a boolean FALSE as 0. So you count how many times type="I" is true and how many times type="O" is true.
Group that by the user ID and show only those who are not equal:

```
SELECT User, Sum([type]="i") AS ins, Sum([type]="o") AS outs, Abs(Sum([type]="i")-Sum([type]="o")) AS diff
FROM myTable
GROUP BY User
HAVING (((Abs(Sum([type]="i")-Sum([type]="o")))>0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating a query which returns one row for each combination of *userid* and *checktype*:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT h.userid, h.checktype
FROM tblHani AS h
WHERE (((h.checktype) In ('I','O')));
```

Note if *checktype* can only be either *I* or *O* in all rows (no Nulls, zero-length string, or other values), that `WHERE` clause is not needed.

Then you can use that as a subquery source for another where you count the *checktype* values for each *userid*, and keep only those whose count is 1:

```sql
SELECT sub.userid, Count(sub.checktype) AS CountOfchecktype
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT h.userid, h.checktype
        FROM tblHani AS h
        WHERE (((h.checktype) In ('I','O')))
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.userid
HAVING (((Count(sub.checktype))=1));
```

With your sample data in a table named *tblHani*, this is the output I get in Access 2010:

```
userid CountOfchecktype
------ ----------------
   592                1
   714                1
```

Comment: Dear Hans; Thanks for your post, the table above is a peace of a table with 95000 record in my Access db, which is used to check the checkin and checkout of employees in the company, What I need is a query to show to employees who checked in morning but forgot to checkout, and vice versa meaning the employees with only check type of 'I' or 'O', the query above didn't bring those people, I tried it on many cases.

Comment: Your question asked to *"select users who have record with checktype of 'I' only or with checktype of 'O' only, not with both"*.  That is what I gave you.  If that is not what you want, fix the question.